# Удалить в массиве - PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Как удалить в массиве всё что меньше 4 символа

Comment: Выложите пример массива

Comment: Напишите условие, вроде это логично.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [array_filter()](http://www.php.su/array_filter)

Пример:

```
$array = array(0 => 'В', 1 => 'Google', 2 => 'обнаружили', 3 => 'нарушений', 4 => 'со', 5 => 'стороны', 6 => 'телеканала', 7 => 'RT');

$res = array_filter($array,function($val){
        return mb_strlen($val)>=4;
});

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Достаточно написать `return mb_strlen($val)>=4;`